# How to add annotations in the diagonal squares of a PairGrid

Tags: python, seaborn, plot-annotations, pairgrid

I want to implement a 5 number summary along the diagonal of a Python Seaborn PairGrid. I tried df.describe() along the diagonal but it did not work. A sample of what I am looking for is the picture at the bottom of this link (https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-data-with-pair-plots-in-python-f228cf529166), which is also pasted here for convenience.[image: Picture Sample]

Comment: Have you looked into his github code in https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/blob/master/pairplots/Pair%20Plots.ipynb ?

Comment: I didnt notice he posted his github address there thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straightforward using `PairGrid` and a custom plotting function for the diagonal:

```
def print_stats(data, **kwargs):
    data = pd.Series(data)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate(data.describe().to_string(), xy=(0.5,0.5), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='center', va='center')

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g = g.map_lower(plt.scatter)
g = g.map_diag(print_stats)
```

[image]